# ~1..toString() vs (~1).toString()

Tags: javascript

```
> ~0..toString(2)
-1
> ~1..toString(2)
-2
> ~2..toString(2)
-11
> ~3..toString(2)
-12
> (~1).toString(2)
'-10'
> (~1).toString(2)
```

Why does `~1..toString(2)` not work, while `(~1).toString(2)` works as expected? What exactly is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Precedence.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)*

`~1..toString(2)` is the same as `~"1"`. The member access operator `.` has precedence, so `toString` is evaluated before the `~`.